# Сравнение двух рядов чисел

Tags: javascript, jquery

В переменных хранятся данные типа 3,5,25,49 
Мне нужно найти пересечения в этих списках.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {  
    for (var j = 0; j < names.length; ++j)
        var prp = a[i] == names[j];
        alert(prp);

            break;
        }
    }
```

Ответом в prp получаю просто true, но мне нужно узнать, какие именно числа совпали и получить их таким же списком через запятую. Как это сделать?

Comment: Числа упорядочены по возрастанию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var common = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {  
  if (names.indexOf(a[i]) != -1)
    common.push(a[i]);
}
console.log(common);
```

> нужно теперь к каждому из совпадений применить некое действие ' var o
>   = document.getElementsByClassName('c' + common); $(o).addClass("bz");' Работает, но только для первого элемента. Как сделать для всех? class
>   выглядит как c+цифра ('c' + common)

Продолжаем использовать наш мощный инструмент - "циклы":

```
for (var j = 0; j < common.length; ++j) {  
  var o = document.getElementsByClassName('c' + common[j]);
  for (var k = 0; k < o.length; k++) {
    $(o[k]).addClass("bz");
  }
}
```

или

```
for (var j = 0; j < common.length; ++j) { 
  $('.c' + common[j]).addClass("bz");
}
```

или

```
common.forEach((item, index) => $('.c' + item).addClass("bz"));
```

Comment: Спасибо, отлично работает!

Comment: Еще можно просто `common = a.filter(v => names.includes(v));`

Comment: Можете еще подсказатать, пожалуйста. Мне нужно теперь к каждому из совпадений применить некое действие ' var o = document.getElementsByClassName('c' + common);
 $(o).addClass("bz");'   Работает, но только для первого элемента. Как сделать для всех? class выглядит как c+цифра ('c' + common)

Comment: @ysmhypno `common.forEach(....)`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Игорь! Очень помог!

Comment: @ysmhypno На здоровье. Успехов!